# Parenthesis in Node Express POST Route not found

Tags: node.js, express

I am mocking a POST route in Express for testing MS XRM.

Working Route:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/data/v8.0/something

app.post('/api/data/v8.0/something', function (req, res) {
  res.send({data:'1234A'});
});
```

Failing Route:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/data/v8.0/something(ABC)/somethingelse

app.post('/api/data/v8.0/something(ABC)/somethingelse', function (req, res) {
  res.send({data:'1234A'});
});
```

Comment: try to replace `(` with `%28` and `)` with `%29`

Comment: Hi, I can't change it on the sending end, but I have tried changing the route to encoded and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses in route paths have special meaning, but it looks like you can escape them like this:

```
app.post('/api/data/v8.0/something[(]ABC[)]/somethingelse', function (req, res) {
  res.send({data:'1234A'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer!